# Quarkus kafka stream to postgres table

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-kafka-streams, quarkus-kafka

I have a use case in which I receive my input data in a Kafka topic. This data has to be transformed and enriched and sent to a PostgreSQL table. My application is using Quarkus Kafka streams to consume data from the input topic and process them. However I do not find any sink/connector to any database (in my case PostgreSQL). If I am not wrong, we can only send the transformed result from a kafkaStream (KStream)  to another Kafka topic or a KTable. Then use another service such as  kafkaConnect or Flink to read the output topic and write the data into the target postgres table.

Is there a way to directly persist the data from Kstream to a PostgreSQL table? As it is a streaming application I do not want to hit the DB for each message and would like to batch insert the data to the table.

Thanks a lot in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that Kafka Streams does not have any built-in way to push data into PostgreSQL. As you noted, Kafka Streams is meant for *data processing with inputs and outputs in Kafka*.

What I would recommend is to continue using Kafka Streams to process the data and massage it into the proper format. Then you can use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html) to sink the data into Postgres. There are many open source Kafka Connectors that work as PG sinks.